# Prevent selection of DataGrid-row. GUI not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

When the user selects one row there is a check whether the row can be selected (the check can't be done beforehand). If the user is not allowed to select the row then the previous row must be selected. It is an **WPF** **MVVM** application.

If I abort the selection in the databound property the SelectedItem property on the DataGrid gets set to the previous value, but it is not reflected in the GUI.

Here is the ViewModel code recreated using the MVVM-light template.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        List<MyItem> myItems = new List<MyItem>{
            new MyItem {ID = 1, Text = "First"},
            new MyItem {ID = 2, Text = "Second"},
            new MyItem {ID = 3, Text = "Third"}
        };

        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>(myItems);
    }


    public const string MyItemsPropertyName = "MyItems";

    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _myItems = null;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _myItems;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_myItems == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _myItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyItems);
        }
    }

    public const string MySelectedItemPropertyName = "MySelectedItem";

    private MyItem _mySelectedItem = null;

    public MyItem MySelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _mySelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            var newValue = value;

            //Do check...
            if (value.ID == 2)
            {
                newValue = _mySelectedItem; 
            }

            Set(() => MySelectedItem, ref _mySelectedItem, newValue);
        }
    }        
}
```

And here is the xaml-code. As you can see the Label is showing the Text-property on the SelectedItem on the DataGrid, it is not databound to the ViewModel.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
        SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserDeleteRows="false" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Text}"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I update the GUI of the DataGrid so that it matches its SelectedItem-property? I. e. the previous row should be highlighted.

Comment: Try to add `IsAsync=True` in the binding of the Label

Comment: Thanks, but the label works fine, it is the GUI of the DataGrid that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing `RaisePropertyChanged` on 'MySelectedItem'? I can't think what else could be the problem since your solution seems to be alright.

There is a different approach you may want to try: you could bind a `RoutedCommand` using a `InvokeCommandAction` and the `CallMethodAction` from Blend Interactivity library.

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Actually, I use RaisePropertyChanged in the original code, but I think Set is a newer way in MVVM-Light where RaisePropertyChanged is called by the Set funktion. I have now confirmed that the property works.

Comment: I have experimented with SelectionChanged too, but with no luck.

Comment: @AxdorphCoder Sorry, I missed that you were using MVVM-Light.